# Alfresco smtp configuration for organisational mail

Tags: email, smtp, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to configure smtp for organisational mail in alfresco 4.2e.

Here is my global configuration

```
mail.host=smthost.abcd.com
mail.port=25
mail.username=sameer@abcd.com
mail.password=password
mail.encoding=UTF-8
mail.from.default=sameer@abcd.com
mail.smtp.auth=false
```

I am unable to send the mail. Here is

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtphost.abcd.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtphost.abcd.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtphost.abcd.com, port: 25;
```

I am able to connect using

```
telnet smtphost.abcd.com25
```

and I am able to ping

Comment: Can you connect from the server that runs Alfresco? Could you have a firewall in place which allows your user to connect to SMTP, but not the user Alfresco runs as?

Comment: @Gagravarr I am running telnet command from the machine in which alfresco is installed. I am able to connect and alfresco is running from my user name only

Answer (score 0):

Your network (most likely your gateway) is telling you it cannot reach the network of abc.efgh.ijkl.com. If you test, make sure to execute telnet from the server giving you the error. Telnet should give you same error message.

```
tcpdump -n -i any port 25
```

will show all outgoing traffic targeting SMTP  and should give you further information about the problem at the network level (such as IP addresses used).

Comment: No the telnet is able to connect the server with no problem

Answer (score 0):

After so much search I found the issue of the problem. The problem occured because java using IPv6 by default. To fix,

1. I disabled IPV6 on windows
2. Set the Java property as `setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Comment: Or you could fix your IPv6 setup so that your machine can talk to the mail server properly over it!